# how to create label element in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var elem2 = document.createElement("label");
elem2.setAttribute("value","something");
labelView.appendChild(elem2);
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work? You are aware that this needs to be attached to the DOM to be visible?

Comment: You should use something like "Webdeveloper toolbar" for firefox to inspect the generated source. So you can see what happens and fix little mistakes like these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Did you add it to the DOM?**

Also, a `<label>` element doesn't make use of the `value` attribute, it uses `innerHTML`.

```
var elem2 = document.createElement('label');
elem2.innerHTML = "something";    
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elem2);
```

Comment: -1 for trying to indicate a label should use innerHTML. And for leaving out the most important part of a label which is the 'for' to associate it with a form element.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the element to the DOM via [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)